# How does spacing of GND via work for shielding?

Tags: via, pcb-antenna

I noticed the YouTuber using GND vias around the PCB antenna. I know this is used to avoid any currents from nearby components coupling to the antenna.

However, he also mentions something about the spacing of the GND vias. How does the spacing determine what frequencies are attenuated near the antenna?

[youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgdUP51JBEw)

[image]

Comment: Can't write an answer now, but looking up the term "Bragg frequency" might be informational.

Comment: @Hearth thank you.

Comment: The following post has a good discussion regarding stitching via spacing for antennas [Stack exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/41871/via-fences-for-noise-reduction-of-a-chip-antenna/).